# LINQ TO SQL Subquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, syntax

I am learning LINQ to SQL. And I want to write a LINQ TO SQL Query for the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From
(select Top 2 * from Data ORDER BY ID DESC)                     
ORDER BY ID
```

According to my understanding it is written something like this;

```
GridView1.DataSource = from ( from data in dbCon.Data ORDER BY data.ID DESC
                          select Top 2 *)ORDER BY data.ID
                          select TOP 1 * ;
```

but it is not correct. Can anybody tell me the correct syntax? and links that can help me learn LINQ TO SQL Syntax for writing subqueries?

Comment: You have simply used to `SQL syntax` and you are no way closer. Better read the documentation first on MSDN and try out LINQ samples from here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I tried to write like you would write a simple select query in LINQ.

Comment: Say for example I dont have any ORDER BY clause. Simple select statements in outer and inner query. What will be syntax then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:-

```
var result = (from x in
               ((from data in db.DATA orderby data.ID descending select data).Take(2))
                orderby x.ID
                select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var query = (from x in db.Data
    select x).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Id).Take(2);




    var query2 = (from y in query
    SELECT y).OrderByDescending(y=> y.Id).Take(1);
```

Comment: You are using lamda expression. I want a sql query like expression

Comment: If you want SQL query like, I would recommend you to the answer below me.